# Animating two circles Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, animation

I have a text file, with the coordinates of two circles on it. I want to produce a live animation of both particles. For some reason the following code crashes

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/text/file.txt', sep=" ", header=None)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_dpi(100)
fig.set_size_inches(7, 6.5)

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 60), ylim=(0, 60))
patch = plt.Circle((5, -5), 6, fc='y')
patch2 = plt.Circle((5, -5), 6, fc='y')

def init():
    patch.center = (df[0][0], df[1][0])
    patch2.center = (df[2][0], df[3][0])
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    return patch, patch2,

def animate(i):
    x, y = patch.center
    x2, y2 = patch2.center
    x = df[0][i]
    y = df[1][i]
    x2 = df[2][i]
    y2 = df[3][i]
    patch.center = (x, y)
    patch2.center = (x2, y2)
    i += 1
    return patch, patch2,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                               init_func=init,
                               frames=360,
                               interval=20,
                               blit=True)
plt.show()
```

The text file that the data is taken from has the columns of X1, Y1, X2 and Y2 where X1 represents the x coordinate of the 1st particle etc.

If I remove all references to the second particle, it works and fully displays the first. Any help would be appreciated.

An example of the text file is the following:

```
40.028255 30.003469 29.999967 20.042583 29.999279 29.997491 
40.073644 30.001855 30.000070 20.090549 30.002644 29.997258 
40.135379 29.996389 29.995906 20.145826 30.005277 29.997931 
40.210547 29.998941 29.996237 20.197438 30.004859 30.002082 
40.293916 30.002021 29.992079 20.248248 29.998585 30.006919
```

(The latter columns arent used in this code) and the exact error message is 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_get_view''.

Thank you

Comment: How specifically does this code crash? Could you edit your question to include the *full* traceback error message? Also, could you share a sample of the data file so that others can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code crashes because you "mixed" matplotlib's "pyplot" and "object-oriented" approaches in a wrong way. Here is the working code. Note that I created `ax`, the axes in which artists are going to be added. On this axes I also applied the axis limits.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

N = 360
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x1": np.linspace(0, 60, N),
    "y1": np.linspace(0, 60, N),
    "x2": np.flip(np.linspace(0, 60, N)),
    "y2": np.linspace(0, 60, N),
})

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

ax.set_xlim(0, 60)
ax.set_ylim(0, 60)

patch = Circle((5, -5), 6, fc='y')
patch2 = Circle((5, -5), 6, fc='y')
ax.add_artist(patch)
ax.add_artist(patch2)

def init():
    patch.center = (df["x1"][0], df["y1"][0])
    patch2.center = (df["x2"][0], df["y2"][0])
    return patch, patch2

def animate(i):
    x, y = patch.center
    x2, y2 = patch2.center
    x = df["x1"][i]
    y = df["y1"][i]
    x2 = df["x2"][i]
    y2 = df["y2"][i]
    patch.center = (x, y)
    patch2.center = (x2, y2)
    i += 1
    return patch, patch2,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                               init_func=init,
                               frames=N,
                               interval=20,
                               blit=True)
plt.show()
```